# Not receiving Microsoft Graph webhook change notifications for "callRecording" event

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I am attempting to utilize Microsoft Graph [change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/change-notifications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) (webhooks) to receive events when a new meeting recording is available.

**Additionally, I am utilizing application permissions for these subscriptions**

I have attempted creating subscriptions for the following resources for change notifications:

- `communications/onlineMeetings/getAllRecordings`
- `communications/onlineMeetings/{onlineMeetingId}/recordings`
- `users/{id}/onlineMeetings/getAllRecordings`

I can confirm that the subscriptions are getting created successfully. Here is an example of a successful response I receive when a subscription is created:

```
{"@odata.context"=>"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity",
 "id"=>"SUBSCRIPTION-ID",
 "resource"=>"communications/onlineMeetings/getAllRecordings",
 "applicationId"=>"APP-ID",
 "changeType"=>"created",
 "clientState"=>nil,
 "notificationUrl"=>"https://test123.ngrok.dev/api/recording_complete",
 "notificationQueryOptions"=>nil,
 "notificationContentType"=>nil,
 "lifecycleNotificationUrl"=>"https://test123.ngrok.dev/api/lifecycle",
 "expirationDateTime"=>"2024-01-05T17:51:34.134Z",
 "creatorId"=>"ea84592d-0dff-4d03-958f-d86718db3128",
 "includeResourceData"=>nil,
 "latestSupportedTlsVersion"=>"v1_2",
 "encryptionCertificate"=>nil,
 "encryptionCertificateId"=>nil,
 "notificationUrlAppId"=>nil}
```

Occasionally, it will receive recording complete notifications the first 1-2 times I end a recording in Teams. But then after that it will suddenly stop receiving notifications.

I have tried this in multiple environments (dev and production environments) and run into the same issue.

I do not run into this issue with other change notification resources such as calendar event created, or updates to an online meeting.

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0):

PM for Microsoft Graph Change Notifications here.

It looks like you're doing all the right things.  Would really like to take a closer look at the issue you're hitting here.

Can you please follow-up through our official channel here:  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support  (choose service "Microsoft Graph")

From there we can dig in on specific SubscriptionID and other info and observe what's happening.